# Upgrading from Selenium 3.11.0 to 4.0.0 can't find Chrome Options setExperimentalOption method

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to upgrade to Selenium 4.  This error occurs: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions.setExperimentalOption(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)

Here is the code used to set the options:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(getChromeOptions());
  private ChromeOptions getChromeOptions() {
    try {
      ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

      HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<>();
      chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
      chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", fileLocation);
      options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
      options.addArguments("start-maximized");
      options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);

      return options;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOG.error("Exception building options", e);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Using chromedriver version 95.0.4638.54

I thought it upgrading would be as simple as changing the version number in the pom. I found this while researching:

*In Selenium 4, DesiredCapabilities have been replaced by Options. To use the Driver class, QAs have to create an Options class, set test requirements, and pass the object to the Driver constructor.*

I may implemented the above incorrectly.
I am at a loss at this point.  Any kind help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: be sure to add jar "selenium-remote-driver-4.0.0.jar" to libs.  The standard options extend the remote driver options.

Comment: also check to be sure you have all dependencies added... all jar files in "lib" folder.  When adding the main jars, don't add the "-sources" files.  I initially had to add the remote driver jar to see the option "setExperimental...", but still needed to add more dependencies to get the type in the constructor to match.  Not sure which one it was.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue but not. Earlier I used `4.0.0-alpha-7` version but upgraded it to `4.0.0` version and I tried and it's working. Below are the `ChromeOptions` of my current project.

**`ChromeOptions`**:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
options.addArguments("start-maximized");


HashMap<String, Object> chromeOptionsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromeOptionsMap.put("plugins.plugins_disabled", new String[] { "Chrome PDF Viewer" });
chromeOptionsMap.put("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);
chromeOptionsMap.put("download.default_directory", "C:\\test\\");
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromeOptionsMap);
```

**Maven dependency**:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Code**:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

Please try following steps:

- Upgrade JDK to 1.8 or > 1.8
- Clean your project workspace through your IDE and rebuild your project with required dependencies only.